# 12v and 48v common ground?

Tags: dc, ground

Building out an RV and have combination of 12v and 48v systems. Not sure if I can share the same grounds.

My biggest concern is what happens if, for example, there’s a short to ground on the  48v side?  I know it will blow a fuse but for a short amount of time won’t that make my 12v system become -36v (I’m putting +48v on the negative)?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Best to connect teh grounds at ONE POINT only . Useful search term : star earthing

Answer (score 0):

They can share a ground, it won't create -36 v on the ground of the 12 v side in the event of a short between 48 v and common ground.

I think the only way to get a 36 volt difference anywhere would be an accidental open break between the grounds combined with an accidental short between 12 and 48, that would create 36 v between the broken grounds.

I am no expert on RVs but I guess there might be other issues to do with electrical noise and sizing of ground conductors.